# Electronic compass soft iron distortion

Tags: interference, compass

I'm making a small autonomous vehicle, it is about 300x300mm in size.
I need to get a heading for the robot.
I currently have a CMPS03 compass but am finding that it is highly sensitive to soft iron interference.
I would like to know if the LSM303 or CHR-6dm would provide a greater resistance to these environmental distortions?

Comment: @user886922 - It is detectting real disturbances in the magnetic field (Luke*). Any other competent sensor will detect the same disturbances.

Comment: *Luke: ... force ...

Answer (score 2):

Likely not, my advice would be to try what shipbuilders do for centuries: mount the compass on the frame and calibrate it so you know what true heading corresponds to each indicated.